# Issue while updating array items inside firebase database

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a simple shopping cart application.

I wanted to add/update/delete user cart items.

Also If already added items I just wanted to update the quantity instead of adding a duplicate entry:

```
const arrayAdd = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion;
const arrayRemove = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove;

this.auth.uid.subscribe(uid => {
      if (uid) {
        this.firestore
          .collection(`users`)
          .doc(uid)
          .valueChanges()
          .subscribe((res) => {
            this.getUserData = res;
            if (this.getUserData.cart && this.getUserData.cart.length) {
              const productExistInCart = this.getUserData.cart.find(({ productName }) => productName === product.productName);
              if (!productExistInCart) {
                this.firestore.doc(`users/${uid}`).update({ cart: arrayAdd(product) });
                return
              } else {
                this.firestore.doc(`users/${uid}`).update({ cart: arrayRemove(productExistInCart) });
                this.firestore.doc(`users/${uid}`).update({ cart: arrayAdd(product) });
                return
              }
            } else {
              this.firestore.doc(`users/${uid}`).update({ cart: [product] })
              return
            }

          });
      }
    });
```

The issue is that when I click on the `addToCart` button for an existing item my database is getting updated in an infinity loop not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You have a listener on a document in the users collection:

```
        this.firestore
          .collection(`users`)
          .doc(uid)
          .valueChanges()
```

When this listener triggers, it updates the document again several times:

```
              if (!productExistInCart) {
                this.firestore.doc(`users/${uid}`).update({ cart: arrayAdd(product) });
                return
              } else {
                this.firestore.doc(`users/${uid}`).update({ cart: arrayRemove(productExistInCart) });
                this.firestore.doc(`users/${uid}`).update({ cart: arrayAdd(product) });
                return
              }
```

Each of these updates will trigger the listener again, because, obviously, the document changed.

You're going to have to either stop using a listener, or figure out how to tell the listener not to make changes that would further trigger it to make more changes.